Object class in kotlin becomes "Null"
I am getting an strange issue,Please help me in that.
I have a framework which is working fine but when I will create the dependency of it to add in any app that time my object class (IdmUtils) coming as null and due to this consuming app got crashed.
Any one have idea why that class becomes null even other object classes are working fine.




If you create a dependency -- I assume you mean a separate jar file -- then it's not visible to your app because you've declared it as internal.

This IdmUtils is not exposed to Shell app, it is used by lib internally.

The NullPointerException isn't thrown by IdmUtils, but by requireActivity() (in the same line).
This is because in some stages of the fragment lifecycle you don't yet have access to an activity (because the fragment is not yet attached)
Solution

Do you really need an activity or is a context enough?
You might move initialisation into a later stage of the fragment lifecycle, see https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle


Yes, I need Activity, I have debug for it but requireActivity() is not null but IdmUtils was null,

This issue is coming due to

remote machine responsible to create dependency

if am creating the dependency manually then this issue is not coming. May be something is wrong with remote machine script.
